# How to edit fields in has-many-through join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, inner-join, has-many-through

I'm an enthusiastic Rails newbie trying to figure out how to edit the fields in the has-many-through join table.

I have three models.

A Players model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: players
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :appearances #, :dependent => true
  has_many :games, :through => :appearances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appearances
end
```

A Games model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: games
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  team         :string(255)
#  date         :date
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  game_innings :integer
#

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :team, :game_innings

  has_many :appearances   #, :dependent => true
  has_many :players, :through => :appearances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appearances

end
```

And an Appearances model:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: appearances
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  player_id      :integer          not null
#  game_id        :integer          not null
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#  innings_played :integer
#

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_id, :game_id

  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player
end
```

When I Edit a player, I would like to be able to list and edit the innings played in each game, or more specifically, I'd like to list and edit the innings_played for each Appearance.

I realize it is incomplete, but here is what my edit.html.erb looks like at the moment:

```
<h1>Editing player</h1>

<%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
    <% if @player.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@player.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this player from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @player.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Opponent</th>
            <th>Innings Played</th>
        </tr>

        <% f.fields_for :games do |games_form| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= games_form.label :team %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>


    </table>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @player %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', players_path %>
```

Grateful for any knowledge you can share.

Answer (score 0):

Change Player and Appearance as the following, Please notice `:appearances_attributes` and `:game_attributes` at the top of each class.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :appearances_attributes

  has_many :appearances #, :dependent => true
  has_many :games, :through => :appearances

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :appearances
end

class Appearance < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :player_id, :game_id, :innings_played, :game_attributes

  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :player

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :game
end
```

Change your view as following, because I don't know exactly what you want to show on your view so I just give an example, you may need to change it to meet your situation.

```
<table>
   <tr>            
   <th>Innings Played</th>
   <th>Team</th>
   </tr>
     <%= f.fields_for :appearances do |appearances_form|%>                              

       <%= appearances_form.fields_for :game do |game_form| %>
         <tr>                               
            <td><%= appearances_form.text_field :innings_played %></td>
            <td><%= game_form.text_field :team %></td>
         </tr>
       <% end %>

    <% end %>

</table>
```

Comment: If I wanted to just list the team names without making them editable, how do I do that from within that fields_for block?  In other words, rather than making the <td><%= game_form.text_field :team %></td> a text_field, how do I just display the name?

Comment: Just remove `appearances_form.fields_for :game`, and replace game_form.text_field by `appearances_form.object.game.team`

Comment: Ah.  I was so close and yet so far.  So much to learn.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I thought that .object would solve the puzzle, but when I go home and tried I received undefined method `team' for nil:NilClass.  I can do appearances_form.object.player.name.  Am I missing something in my models?

Comment: Try checking if all your Appearance objects has a player. I suspect some of your Appearance objects don't have a player.